# Is there any way to sort non stackable Items in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am making a automatic item sorter for the piglins but you get non-stackable items and i want to seperate these non-stackable items so there may be in 1 chest splash pot of fire resis but in the other chest there may be regular fire pots.

Comment: Googling "minecraft potion sorter" gives some results that look promising.